# VBA. Assigning range to header name instead of column letter

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of using AU and AV to find my columns, can I find my columns by looking for actual header name?

pseudocode:
Ie `arr = ws.Range("headernameone1:headernametwo" & lastR).Value2`

Code:

```
lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Getting last row with column A
arr = ws.Range("AU1:AV" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing. This array is for AU and AV
arrtwo = ws.Range("AC1:AD" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing. This array is for AC and AD
```

Comment: Look into [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: `ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastR,application.MATCH(headernameone1,ws.Range("1:1"),0)),ws.Cells(lastR,application.MATCH(headernametwo,ws.Range("1:1"),0))).Value2`

Comment: Or use a table (Ctrl+T), and you can refer to columns by their headers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim c1,c2, rw as Range, lastR as long

lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Getting last row with column A

Set rw = ws.rows(1) 'row with column headers
c1 = application.match("headernameone", rw, 0)
c2 = application.match("headernametwo", rw, 0)

if not iserror(c1) and not iserror(c2) then    'found both column headers?
    arr = ws.range(rw.cells(c1),rw.cells(c2)).resize(lastR).value2
else
    msgbox "One or both required column headers not found!"
end if
```